# Default context path in JMeter

Tags: web-applications, jmeter, load-testing

I am using `HTTP Request Defaults` setting for multiple HTTP request for a web app. I would like to have common context path for all request like it is possible with hostname and port and to provide only relative path for each specific request. Is this possible?

```
|--- shared config --|
localhost:8080/my-app/relative-path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.

But you can variabilize the "my-app" part by using a jmeter [User Defined variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables).